# Facebook fan page photo's scraping

Tags: facebook, screen-scraping, web-scraping, fan-page

We want to add a facebook fan page photo competition to our fan page. The meaning is that ppl can upload photo's and others can like them. The person with the most likes on his photo wins a price.

Now i was wondering if anyone knows a good idea on how to get a snapshot of all the photo's on a given moment. So that when we want to stop the contest we get an overview of the number of likes of all the persons.

Some good website scraping tools? maybe a usefull facebook app? some other alternatives?

greets,
Daan

Answer (score 0):

I can think of some fancy ways to do this, but the easiest approach would be to just download the facebook fan page at the moment you want to stop the competition, so that you can view the results later.